# Getting StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED when trying to make gRPC call to Tensorflow Serving Kubernetes pod

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes, grpc, tensorflow-serving, grpc-python

We have a Flask server, which makes gRPC calls to a Tensorflow Serving POD(which uses Official tf-serving docker image) that serves around 20 tensorflow models. Both Flask microservice and Tf-Serving microservice are deployed on Kubernetes.
For 0.5-1% of the requests made from Flask to Tf-Serving, Flask server is throwing an RpcError - **StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED**

There is a similar issue on github: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1265 .Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to proxy issue. To get rid of Deadline Exceed issue, try:

```
import os
if os.environ.get("http_proxy"):
    del os.environ["http_proxy"]
if os.environ.get("https_proxy"):
    del os.environ["https_proxy"]
```